# Apple In-App Restoring Purchases: Am I responsible for validating a purchase before I allow a “Restore Purchase” request to go through?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Am I responsible for validating a purchase before I allow a “Restore Purchase” request to go through? This is a non-consumable purchase. What's supposed to happen when a Restore Purchase request goes through for an apple ID that did not make the purchase?

The reason I ask is that when I was testing the restore purchase functionality, I first signed out of the sandbox test account which the original purchase was made on. And when prompted during the restore request, I signed in with an account that *had not* made a purchase, and the purchase (with the in-app purchase content) was restored just fine under that account.

Is that what would happen with any random user that hit the restore button? Here's apple's document on restoring purchases:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

It mentions that the user will be prompted for credentials but it makes no mention of what it would do if it was a different app store account from the original. It might just be asking because it wants *someone* to be authenticated first.

Comment: Sounds like you coded your logic incorrectly. If you logged into a user account that didn't make the purchase but your code granted access anyway, that's your bug, not a problem with how the restore purchase process works.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? That's what my question was to begin with: Am I responsible for validating a purchase before I allow a “Restore Purchase” request to go through? Like I mentioned, the documentation says upon Restore request the user will be prompted for credentials. Why prompt the user at all if it's going to allow the restore to go through regardless of the credentials given?

Comment: But the restore is not going through. Your code (presumably based on your description) is mistakenly granting access regardless. If you want help with your code you need to post relevant code showing your restoration logic.

Comment: For example, https://www.howtogeek.com/243293/how-to-restore-in-app-purchases-on-an-iphone-or-ipad/ states the following: "You’ll need to authenticate with the App Store after you do this, providing your Apple ID password. The app will then check the receipts on the app store to see what you’ve purchased and restore the purchases on your device." Sounds like it should block a restore attempt from accounts that didn't make the purchase. However, this isn't Apple's developer documentation. I would like to have some confirmation if this is really the expected behavior.

Comment: No, the restore *is* going through. Restores work just fine. I just want to know what the expected behavior *from Apple* is when an app *fails to prevent* a restore request from being made by someone who didn't make the IAP. For example, suppose someone hacked the app and simply bypassed the the purchase validation code so that the purchase request is made anyway. Would Apple just restore the purchase and the hosted content regardless of what user was authenticated while making the restore request?

Comment: BTW, I've got validation logic to verify purchases. I'm just trying to find out if the app store is *supposed* to reject restore requests from accounts that didn't make the purchase. The restore seems to have gone through for an account that didn't make the purchase and apple restored the purchase. However, this app and IAP aren't released to the App store yet. This is a sandbox environment only which might behave differently.

Comment: You have this all confused. It doesn't matter what login a user uses and whether they actually made the purchase to begin with or not. Your job is to write code that properly kicks off the restoration process and listens to all of the resulting payment queue events. It is the properly handling, by you, of those events that determines whether you should grant the IAP to the user or not. Those events tell you what was restored (if anything). If the user logs in with an account that didn't make a purchase, then you won't get a valid restore transaction so don't grant the user access in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Maybe I asked my question poorly. I think this technical note is what I was looking for " StoreKit does not call the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method when there are no restorable products." Unfortunately, this wasn't stated in their "Restoring Completed Transactions" doc so it was unclear to me.  The answer to my original question is "No, Apple will not restore the purchase". I created a fresh test account and retested and everything worked correctly. Unbeknownst to me, that other test account actually *had* made the purchase before which created my confusion.

Comment: To be clear, Apple doesn't restore any purchases, ever. It only tells you about appropriate transactions, if any. It is your code's responsibility to handle the transactions (or lack there of) appropriately by granting or denying the user access to certain functionality in your app.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. However, it does deliver In-App content or not. If a user is not signed in who made the purchase before, it appears to me that they *will not* deliver it to the device no matter what you do.